# Unable to access vue data in basic modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to loop and reference vue data values within a modal and am getting an error that the field needs to be reactive, despite the values being provided in the component initialization. Any idea why this is?

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mwLbw11k/2618/

JS

```
// register modal component
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template'
})

// start app
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myData: [{'first': 'Matt', 'last': 'Smith'}, {'first': 'Tom', 'last': 'Brady'}],
    showModal: false
  }
})
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
  <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header">
              default header
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <slot name="body">
              <ul>
                <li v-for="user in myData"> {{ user.first }} {{ user.last }}</li>
              </ul>
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">
              default footer
              <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                OK
              </button>
            </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</script>

<!-- app -->
<div id="app">
  <button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">Show Modal</button>
  <!-- use the modal component, pass in the prop -->
  <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
  </modal>
</div>
```

Vue Warning

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "myData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yous should add `myData` to `modal` component props

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template',
  props: ['myData']
})
```

and then pass it from parent like this:

```
  <modal v-if="showModal" :my-data="myData" @close="showModal = false">
  </modal>
```

Comment: For clarity, can you explain why this would work? why I would need to make these changes? thanks

Comment: Because the data you've passed to your app (`new Vue`) is not automatically passed to the `modal` component. The component should receive it from its props (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Composing-with-Components).

Comment: If it was not the case - then in the context of `modal` component it would not be clear where the data comes from.

Comment: updated the answer according to @volodymyr-symonenko fixes

Answer (score 1):

corrected [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/simati/1h1dvpLa/) from Bsalex

```
<modal v-if="showModal" :my-data="myData" @close="showModal = false">
```